# Слишком большое число для JS, расчет в итоге не верный

Tags: javascript

Перевести число в двоичную систему счисления и посчитать его единицы. На вход подается большое число например: 8816912545 
 Я получаю в двоичной системе число 1101100001110110100010100001, хотя ответ: 1000001101100001110110100010100001, подскажите способ как мне иначе реализовать мою функцию. Также будет интересно посмотреть другой способ подсчета единиц.

```
const countBits = ((n) => {
    const bitRes = (n >>> 0).toString(2)
    const getSplitBitres = bitRes.split('')
    return getSplitBitres.reduce((acc, el) => {
        return acc + +el
    }, 0)
})
```

Comment: Что вы хотели сделать с помощью `n >>> 0`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Оператор `>>>` обрезает свои аргументы до 32-х бит. Если `n` не попадает в диапазон *[-2147483648, 2147483647]*, число бит будет занижено.

В данной конкретной задаче можно обойтись без битовых операций (почти, `n & 1` не искажает результат, так как работает только с одним младшим битом):

```
const countBits = n => {
    n = Math.abs(n); // если нужно обрабатывать n < 0.
    let bits = 0;
    for (; n != 0; n = Math.floor(n / 2)) {
        bits += n & 1;
    }
    return bits;
}
```

Ваш вариант тоже можно починить:

```
// const bitRes = (n >>> 0).toString(2)
const bitRes = n.toString(2)
```